# Send Custom Verification Email with Template Parameter (Simple Email Service)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Using AWS Java Api (SES), I have the following code

```
@Test
@DisplayName("send custom verification email")
void sendCustomVerificationEmail() {
    SendCustomVerificationEmailRequest sendCustomVerificationEmailRequest = new SendCustomVerificationEmailRequest();
    sendCustomVerificationEmailRequest.setEmailAddress("contact@company.com");
    sendCustomVerificationEmailRequest.setTemplateName("MyMailTemplate");
    SendCustomVerificationEmailResult sendCustomVerificationEmailResult = amazonSimpleEmailService.sendCustomVerificationEmail(sendCustomVerificationEmailRequest);
    System.out.println(sendCustomVerificationEmailResult.getMessageId());

}
```

I got receive the verification email, I can click in the link and then change the status of the email (Pending->Success).

My Question is, How Could I to have a tracking of my verification request with my user request, because I cannot change the email body with a token, or get a token of the verification request.

With the tracking I can be trusted to send mails with his verified email address and with the token I can be trusted to send mails with his tracked email adress.